# Select dropdown option by value using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

I have select following html structure

```
<select id="mainMenu" data-mini="true" name="select-choice-min">
   <option value="1">1</option>
   <option value="2">2</option>
   <option value="3">3</option>
   <option value="4">4</option>
   <option value="5">5</option>
   <option value="6">6</option>   
</select>
```

on page load I want initially set option with value 5 so I tried (but nothing changed)

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   $('#mainMenu option').eq(5).prop('selected', true);
})
```

I'm using jQuery 1.8.3 and jQuery mobile since this is mobile website

```
<script src="/Scripts/jquery-1.8.3.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/jquery.mobile-1.4.2.js"></script>
```

**UPDATE:**

I just realize that every code from posted answers works (as well as mine), #mainMenu option value is set to desired value (5) but it's text doesn't change (in any of this scenarios). Is this normal and is there workaround for this.

I tried `$("mainMenu").text("5");`

Comment: Is there a reason not to just code the `selected` attribute on option 5 in your HTML?

Comment: jQuery mobile probably recreates the select as an unordered list with styling.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Refresh**

> This is used to update the custom select to reflect the native select
>   element's value.If the number of options in the select are different
>   than the number of items in the custom menu, it'll rebuild the custom
>   menu. Also, if you pass a true argument you can force the rebuild to
>   happen.

```
$("#mainMenu").val("5");
$("#mainMenu").selectmenu('refresh', true);
```

Take a look here [Select menus](http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.0rc3/docs/forms/selects/methods.html)

[**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/6Ls6Lgz8/4/)

Answer (score 1):

This is working fine:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   $('#mainMenu option').eq(5).prop('selected', true);
})
```

**[Check JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/07ym821a/)**

But `.eq(5)` is index and start from 0 so if you want to select value=5, use `.eq(4)`.

Also you can use this:

```
$("#mainMenu").val("5");
```

and also you can set the 5 as default selected value in your HTML code manually like this:

```
<option value="5" selected>5</option>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using jquery =>

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   $('#mainMenu').val("5");
})
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var dropdown = $('#mainMenu');
        dropdown.val(5);
        dropdown.change();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way would be:

```
$(function () {
   $('#mainMenu').find("option[value='5']").each(function(){
       if ($(this).val() == 5) {
          $(this).prop("selected", true);
          $('#mainMenu').trigger("updated");
          $('#mainMenu').val(5).trigger("change");
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This code worked for me. For example if you have list of countries in HTML:

```
<select id="countries" name="countries">
    <option value="0">Argentina</option>
    <option value="1">Brazil</option>
    <option value="2">England</option>
    <option value="3">Ireland</option>
    <option value="4">United States</option>
</select>
```

In JQuery you can select England this way:

```
$('#countries').val("2");
```

[Demo Link - Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Jildirim/azsourjy/11/)